# Если уже не сделал / если ещё не сделал?

Tags: выбор-слов

Ситуация такая: кто-то держит человека в заложниках. Его друг просит другого о помощи со словами: "Помоги, его собираются убить. **Если уже не убили**". Так вот у меня вопрос: его **уже** не убили или **ещё** не убили? Или тут оба варианта подходят? Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Евгений Лукин. Клопики (2013) "Представляю, что за переполох поднимется (**если уже не поднялся**) во
>   всех учреждениях ― частных и государственных".
>
> Юрий Трифонов. Предварительные итоги (1970) "Попросил Атабалы позвать Валю, медсестру, **если ещё не убежала** на работу, измерить давление".

Получается, что выбор слова тут зависит только от того, какой смысл вкладывает автор? Что-то, скорее всего, **уже** произошло или **ещё** не произошло?

Comment: Говорите все что хотите, но я так не могу сказать. Что-то мешает.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, зачем же вы свой ответ удалили? Собрали бы разные мнения, интересно же, кто как думает)

Comment: Просто никто не согласился с моим видением, вот я и усомнился в нём. :( Можете проголосовать за восстановление, если хотите.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, а как? Хочу) Пусть будет, может, тоже со временем голоса соберёт, будут единомышленники. Вам разве не интересно?) Может, другие стесняются свой ответ, схожий с вашим, писать, т.к. у них низкий рейтинг репутации, а вы тут пользуетесь определённым авторитетом, им будет легче, что они не одни не согласны.

Comment: Оказалось, его сразу можно восстановить без голосования)) Спасибо за поддержку, наверно, интересно. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Получается, что выбор слова тут зависит только от того, какой смысл
>   вкладывает автор? Что-то, скорее всего, уже произошло или ещё не
>   произошло?

На мой взгляд, даже от этого не зависит. Семантика конструкций в общем-то одинакова, а различия можно углядеть только в акцентах - на уровне авторского отношения.

Я исхожу из того, что все усматриваемые различия (включая прямо и косвенно упомянутые в других ответах) субъективны. Можно так трактовать - а можно и эдак. А это говорит о том, что объективных смысловых различий нет.

Я лично вижу стилистические (ну или акцентные) различия в том, что "ещё" предполагает некоторую обязательность события сейчас или в будущем (убийства в данном случае), а "уже" скорее говорит о возможности такого в прошлом. Но допускаю, что кто-то имеет прямо противоположное мнение - и доказать друг другу мы ничего объективно не сможем.

Вообще тема того, как антонимичные по словарю значения де-факто выступают в качестве синонимов, сама по себе интересна, но развивать ее тут нет никакой возможности. Ограничусь констатацией того факта, что разбираемый случай такой странной синонимии не противоречит общей грамматике языка, но возможен только с отрицанием глагола. Вариант "если еще убили" что-то уже другое означает, если вообще возможен.

> 2) А если написать так: Помоги, его собираются убить. Если еще не
>   убили.
>
> Тогда у второго предложения формально теряется смысл. Разумеется,
>   можно собираться убить кого-то, если он еще живой. И помочь можно
>   только в этом случае.

Вот тут я согласен. Но это уже привлечение контекста, а вопрос-то стоит более общий, как я понял.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ! Вот прям всё, о чём я думала, но не могла сформулировать. Как раз возможность антонимами сказать одно и то же меня и удивила. И да, я заметила, что это возможно только в случае наличия **не** при глаголе. Я всё утро перечитывала ответы, но никак не могла выбрать.

Answer (score 2):

Мой ответ: возможны оба варианта.

Могу привести множество достаточно старых цитат в пользу **уже**. Например:

> Он <ревизор> может приехать во всякий час, **если уже не приехал** и не
>   живет где-нибудь инкогнито (Н.В. Гоголь, Ревизор). (Цитирую по словарю Ю. Апресяна)
>
> На днях приедет к вам, **если уже не приехал**, Иноземцев, которому отдай,
>   пожалуйста, это письмо. (Н.В. Гоголь, ПСС, письма)
>
> Уходить Воронов будет прежде всего по реке, если... уже не ушел. (Н.И. Дементьев, Две повести, 1979)
>
> Социализм родился у нас во Франции, милостивый государь — да и во
>   Франции же умрет, **если уже не умер**. (И.С. Тургенев, Человек в серых очках)

Answer (score 2):

"Уже" и "ещё" в данном контексте имеют *разный* смысл и ссылаются на *разные* части первого высказывания.

> Помоги, его собираются убить. Если **уже** не убили.

Здесь элемент "помоги" - просьба о помощи. Второе высказывание ссылается не на неё, а на сообщение "его собираются убить". Добавочное высказывание "если уже не убили" уточняет, что первое сообщение верно в случае, если не произошло худшее: возможно, его уже убили (есть и такое опасение). Помощь нужна в любом случае - даже если поздно.

Что все это будет значить, если вместо "уже" употребить "ещё"?

> Помоги, его собираются убить. Если *ещё* не убили.

В отличие от первого варианта, второе высказывание ссылается скорее на обращение "помоги". Если же попытаться вместо этого логически связать высказывания "его собираются убить" "если ещё не убили", смысл выходит странным: *если его ещё не убили (а должны были убить и скорее всего, убили), то сохраняются намерения убить, - так что помоги (вдруг не убили)*. Но и первый смысл странный: *помоги, если его **ещё** не убили* (а если убили, то "отбой" помощи). Адресат, конечно, поймёт, что на самом деле хотели сказать (он в опасности, надо что-то делать), но это вариант гораздо менее вразумительный и связный, чем вариант с "**уже**", который предпочтителен.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, я считаю, ***ещё.*** Это подтверждается и вашими примерами: более старый надёжнее, тогда грамотность была выше.

В ***отрицательных*** предложениях встречается *"ещё не",* а в ***утвердительных*** — "уже". Действие либо предположительно (в условных), либо определённо (в обычных утверждениях) произошло. В английском есть аналогичный пример: *тоже* — ‘also’ или ‘too’, а *тоже не* — ‘either’ (ставится в конец фразы).

*Примеры:*

Я **ещё не** съел бутерброд.
Я **уже** съел бутерброд.

Позови его. Если, конечно, он **ещё не** смылся.
Позови его. Если он **уже** смылся, тогда постарайся догнать его и привести.

Как видно из них, в утвердительных предложениях (и в обычных, и в условных) используется "уже", а в отрицательных — "ещё" (повторюсь, не претендую на объективность, это моё мнение).

Comment: Артем, вы в комментариях к вопросу удивлялись, что никто не согласился с вами. Это побудило меня подать эту реплику. Я не могу сказать, что я не согласен с вами. Но тут такое дело... У вас как база рассматриваются примеры с безусловными конструкциями. И выводы из них делаются. А ведь без грамматической условности (наличия "если") все соверенно по-другому смотрится. Проблема именно в использовании "уже" и "еще" в условных придаточных. Причем по семантике это какой-то особый тип придаточных, детально не разобранный даже в "Корпусной грамматике".

Comment: Так вот, возможность использования "уже" вместо "еще" появляется только этой конструкции "если (уже) не ...". Я подозреваю, что тут следы какой-то очень давней истории, когда "уже" еще воспринималось как отрицание "же" (об этом - у Фасмера).. Поэтому получалось этакое двойное отрицание, возможное только в условных конструкциях . Но это, во-перавх, такая седая древность, а во-вторых в нашем формате совершенно неподъемная по объему тема. так что лучше всего просто не вылезать в анализе за пределы условной конструкции, не выискивая параллелей с конструкцией повествовательной. Как-то так...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, Бегемотус! Как же нет условных примеров? А последние два? Первый как раз с НЕ. Я их специально сделал похожими на пример Юлии, то есть по сути одну мысль разбил на два предложения. А во втором я показываю, что если убрать отрицание, "ещё" превращается в "уже".

Comment: *А последние два* - так это вроде как не примеры, а выводы. Нет?

Comment: Нет! Это я такие примеры придумал.

Comment: Ну тогда я вообще вашей логики не понял. Четыре примера непонятно какого утверждения - а вывод-то где?

Comment: Я думал, вывод очевиден, но раз нет, тогда сейчас напишу.

Comment: Ох... Артем, не суетитесь. Смысл моей реплики был в том, что вы пытаетесь что-то вывести, базируясь на примерах повествовательных конструкций. А я считаю, что это невозможно, ибо без "если" вариант с "уже" невозможен в принципе. Поэтому ваш вывод заведомо сомнителен. И я совсем не требую от вас каких-то сиюмиинутных действий. Просто отвечал на ваше сетования, что с вами не согласились.

Comment: *...Ибо без "если" вариант с "уже" невозможен в принципе* — я так и не понял, чем предпоследний пример плох?

Comment: Не понял. А где я сказал, что он плох? Он не плох сам по себе, вполне грамотный, но абсолютно не связан с тем что вы цитируете. Я так переспрошу. ***Это пример чего?***

Comment: С тем, что я цитирую? Так я не цитирую, а придумал примеры. Пример чего? Пример отрицательного условного предложения с ещё/уже, каким я его вижу.

Answer (score 1):

1) Я бы написала так: *Помоги, его собираются убить. Если **уже** не убили.*

Доя выбора варианта нужно понять **смысл информации**. В первом предложении приведена просьба о помощи и указана причина.

**А о чем говорит второе предложение**? Это уже развитие темы, где высказано предположение: Не исключено, что его ***уже*** убили.  (Поэтому действовать надо срочно, чтобы успеть помочь.)

2) А если написать так: *Помоги, его собираются убить. Если  **еще** не убили.*

Тогда у второго предложения формально  **теряется смысл.** Разумеется, можно **собираться** убить кого-то, если он **еще** живой. И помочь можно только в этом случае.

Таким образом, второе предложение в этом варианте **формально** имеет **нулевую информацию**: непонятно, что нового оно добавляет к уже сказанному.

**Намек** на то, что надо действовать срочно? Но этот смысл  более правильно, точно, а также убедительно и эмоционально передает наречие ***уже***.

Конечно, оба наречия являются в этом сообщении **словами-сигналами**, которые говорят о необходимой **срочности** действий. Конечно, содержание всем  понятно, и никто не будет  присматриваться к грамматике и семантике, вот и **кажется**, что оба варианта подходят.

Но  если речь идет о формальной правильности предложения, то следует выбрать наречие ***уже***.

Answer (score 1):

**Немного о наречиях ЕЩЕ и УЖЕ**

Этот ответ заменяет комментарий к ответу Артёма.

Хорошо, что вы вернули ответ, а то я его  не успела толком прочитать.  Всё там похоже на правду, кроме одного: наречия ЕЩЕ и УЖЕ **не так просты, чтобы задать им жесткие правила.**

Загляните в словарь, и вы увидите, что они могут быть даже **синонимами**, причем в чистом виде, без всяких НЕ. Из словаря: ЕЩЁ 3. (при обозначении времени, места). = Уже.

Тогда мы получаем: *Этот дом построен **еще** в начале века. Этот дом построен **уже** в начале века.*

Вот вам и **антонимы**! Оттенки смысла разные, **а, кстати,  какие?**

Поэтому я считаю, что нужно рассматривать каждый КОНКРЕТНЫЙ случай. Вот давайте я  приведу пример, похожий на ваш.

(1) *Представляешь, они собираются позвать на вечеринку этого Н., если **еще** не позвали.*

(2) *Представляешь, они собираются позвать  на вечеринку этого Н., если **уже** не позвали*.

Участники диалога не знают, приглашен ли Н., но у них **два предположения**: (а) его только собираются позвать; (б) возможно, его уже позвали.

И вот в первом предложении содержится только предположение (а), а вторая часть предложения ничего нового не дает. Во втором же предложении содержится информация (а) и (б).

Какой вариант более правилен и информативен?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ-комментарий! А мне в первом и (б) видится! Просто мне естественно выражать ту же мысль с помощью "ещё", что вам с "уже".

Comment: Может быть, и так, если учесть. что эти слова (по словарю) могут быть синонимами.  Вот и стоит приглядеться к примеру с домами, который я привожу.  Думается мне,что дело не в грамматических схемах в нашем подсознании, а в реальном чувстве языка. Будучи синонимами,  наречия имеют в этих примерах разную КОННОТАЦИЮ, а это зависит от реакции собеседника на предыдущее высказывание (то есть он контекста). Вот такой у нас язык, умеющий передавать самые тонкие оттенки значений, и именно этой способностью мы владеем на уровне интуиции.

Comment: С домами — да, я вижу разницу. С "ещё" смысл " так давно уже стоял", а с "уже" — "к началу века уже успели построить!"

Comment: А вам не кажется, что это разная реакция участника диалога  на предыдущее высказывание собеседника, например: Это совсем новый дом . - Какой новый?!  Он уже в начале века был построен. // Это старинный дом? - Да, он еще в начале века был построен.  Вот и получается, что дело не в привычке к тому или иному наречию, но все зависит от текущей ситуации, от того, что уже сказано раньше.  А вот мы решаем задачки без контекста (обратите внимание).

Comment: Кажется, конечно. Полностью согласен с примерами! Вот только в отрицательном условном у меня язык не очень поворачивается сказать "уже" в любом диалоге. Хотя!.. В случае "если **только**" уже готов сказать и "уже" вроде, в частности и в моём предпоследнем примере.

Comment: Подумал получше и понял следующее: в своём примере я бы всё же оставил "ещё", а в примере Юлии поменял бы на "уже" при наличии "только". Подробнее напишу в ответе (либо старый продолжу, либо в новом).

Comment: Я ударение ставлю на УЖЕ, это ключевое слово. А для вашего ударения на ЕЩЁ я придумала такой текст: "Помоги, его собираются убить. Если еще не убИли, конечно".  Тогда грамматика правильная (если еще не убили, то собираются это сделать), инверсия условного придаточного объясняется. Ну а в краткой реплике слово "конечно" опускается. Да, Артем, вот всегда надо отстаивать свое мнение, даже если оно единственное среди других. С вашей помощью получше присмотрелись к наречиям.

Answer (score 1):

Меня осенила новая мысль, которую я решил оформить в виде ещё одного ответа.

Хочу рассмотреть пример Юлии. Повторюсь, что я предлагаю выбрать "ещё":

> Помоги, его собираются убить. Если **ещё** не убили.

Здесь я делаю ударение на "убили". Но если добавить слово "только", я бы поменял "ещё" на "уже" и сместил бы ударение на это "уже":

> Помоги, его собираются убить. Если только **уже́** не убили.

Но мне кажется, что такой "фокус" не пройдёт с предпоследним примером из моего первого ответа, а всё потому, что там глагол не повторяется.

Comment: Ага, поняла вас. Интересно) А я и без "только" расставляю акценты так же, как и вы) _что-то я намудрила тут с так же, как и, да? :)_

Comment: Хорошо, что одинаково!)